# R plotly fill color, font, and legend location

Tags: r, plotly

```
elw <- structure(list(year = 1975:1979, x10006 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
   x12018 = c(285.4309, 265.1403, 369.1682, 604.1203, 587.2926
), x19000 = c(26.48335, 36.45504, 37.28563, 126.8903, 182.8447
), x20000 = c(229.9651, 369.8476, 496.058, 504.2717, 445.3687
), x99999 = c(1707.498, 2223.986, 2599.086, 2661.213, 3207.065
)), .Names = c("year", "x10006", "x12018", "x19000", "x20000", 
"x99999"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame") 

elw_stack <- structure(list(year = 1975:1979, x10006 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    x12018 = c(285L, 265L, 369L, 604L, 587L), 
    x19000 = c(312L, 302L, 406L, 731L, 770L), 
    x20000 = c(542L, 671L, 903L, 1235L, 1216L), 
    x99999 = c(2249L, 2895L, 3502L, 3896L, 4423L)), 
    .Names = c("year", "x10006", "x12018", "x19000", "x20000", "x99999"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

With the data aboce, I have generated a plotly chart in R using the following code:

```
install.packages("plotly")
library(plotly)

plot_ly(data = elw_stack, x = ~year, y = ~x10006, fill="tonexty", mode="lines",
        text = round(elw$x10006, 0), hoverinfo='x+text+name', name="x10006") %>%
  add_trace(y=~x12018, mode="lines", type = "scatter", text = round(elw$x12018,0),
            hoverinfo='x+text+name', name="x12018") %>%
  add_trace(y=~x19000, mode="lines", text=round(elw$x19000,0), 
            hoverinfo='x+text+name', name="x19000") %>%
  add_trace(y=~x20000, mode="lines", text=round(elw$x20000,0), 
            hoverinfo='x+text+name', name="x20000") %>%
  add_trace(y=~x99999, mode="lines", text=round(elw$x99999,0), 
            hoverinfo='x+text+name', name="x99999") %>%
  layout(yaxis=list(title="Y axis label"))
```

I am still struggling to do three things, though:

1. Change the fill color to specific RGB-code colors of my choosing. (I attempted the plotly command `fillcolor` but am not sure if I'm implementing it correctly.)
2. Change the font style of all the text (specifically to Gotham Narrow).
3. Lower the legend so that it's not positioned at the top of the chart.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: for your legend location, it's in the documentation; just add layout(legend = list(x = 0.5, y = 0)); play with x and y

Comment: did you manage to figure this out? I'm facing the same issue as well but it changes the color on the chart but not on the legends... :-(

Comment: @adilapapaya I don't believe I did, sorry :( Please post below if you do find out, though!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that does what you want. I just used the font "Times":

```
clrs <- c('#66c2a5','#fc8d62','#8da0cb','#e78ac3')

plot_ly(data = elw_stack, x = ~year, y = ~x10006, fill="tonexty", mode="lines",
        text = round(elw$x10006, 0), hoverinfo='x+text+name', name="x10006", type = "scatter") %>%
  add_trace(y=~x12018, text = round(elw$x12018, 0), name="x12018", fillcolor = clrs[1]) %>%
  add_trace(y=~x19000, text = round(elw$x19000, 0), name="x19000", fillcolor = clrs[2]) %>%
  add_trace(y=~x20000, text = round(elw$x20000, 0), name="x20000", fillcolor = clrs[3]) %>%
  add_trace(y=~x99999, text = round(elw$x99999, 0), name="x99999", fillcolor = clrs[4]) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title="Y axis label"),
         legend = list(x = 1, y = 0),
         font = list(family = "Times"))
```

[image]